# mysql_fetch_array is not working in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

This is the code I have so far:-

```
$db = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getPluginResource('db')->getDbAdapter();
$sql = "select * from users";
$result = $db->fetchAll($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Password</th>
    </tr>
";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

I am Trying this but I recieved this error:-

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in /var/www/datashow/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 35
```

Comment: `$result` is the actual result you are looking for. Just loop through it and print the result. It is not the resource. You don't have to use any kind of fetch function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zend_Db does not return mysql result objects. You don't use MySQL's functions, ever, when using the Zend_Db abstraction layer; you use Zend's functions instead. In this case, `findAll` already returned the data as an array.

Comment: @root: What do you mean? You already have the data in an array.

Comment: @root: If you don't know how to print out the contents of an array you need to learn PHP before trying to work out Zend Framework.

Answer (score 0):

@root:

You already fetched the result using  `$result = $db->fetchAll($sql);`
then why did u use `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))`     ?

I would recommend you to check, what data are in your $result variable at first, using `print_r($result)`  .
then you can use a foreach or some other efficient loop to echo the values.

```
foreach($result as  $resultItems){ // echo value in $resultItems}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($result as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
```